# Would revisiting the UK on a multiple entry visit visa that is still valid cause any problems at the border?

Tags: visas, uk, borders, multiple-entry

My girlfriend is Vietnamese, we just returned from visiting my parents and friends. As we had such a fantastic time we want to visit again at Christmas as her visa is multiple-entry and valid until the 8th January (we would need to be leaving by the 3rd anyway).

However this is of course a recent development I was curious if she would encounter any problems at the border as we didn't declare this second trip during her visa application.

Finally she will be changing jobs (albeit pretty much the same thing just a different company) could that cause problems?

Answer (score 1):

The whole point of a multiple entry visa is that you are allowed to enter multiple times. As long as you abide by any other terms of the visa and don't look like you are trying to live in the country you should be fine.